# Send MSG to AMQP in Jmeter using Protobuf

Tags: jmeter, rabbitmq, protocol-buffers, load-testing

Is there a way to use jmeter to send protobuf messages to rabbitmq? I would like to simulate making a request to a service that will deserialize the message, process and store in a DB. This is not a http request. The message will be published to rabbitmq and a service will consume it. The reply is also a protobuf message.

I have not been able to find a way to configure jmeter to use protobuf messages except sending a simple message containing a string to AMQP using AMQP Publisher. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any existing plugin so you will either need to add the relevant .jars containing [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/java-client.html) and [Protocol Buffers](https://protobuf.dev/getting-started/javatutorial/) to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and implement your test logic using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy).

You can take a look at the following plugins (basically you need their combination)

- [JMeter-Rabbit-AMQP](https://github.com/jlavallee/JMeter-Rabbit-AMQP)
- [protobuf-test](https://github.com/xykong/protobuf-test)